# "alias" attribute causing program crash on windows

Tags: c, gcc, attributes

I've a small little Windows (7) GCC (4.8.1 64-bit) console program I'm using to just test some stuff out,. One of the headers I've written uses the `alias` attribute which I'm fairly sure worked as expected the last time I used the file it's in.

Now however, when I run the program when it calls the alias Windows tells me the program has stopped working! If I call the function directly without the alias, everything works as expected...

The code in question is in a file `foo.h` that is included in the `.c` file that holds `main()` which calls the alias.

foo.h:

```
#include<stdint.h>

#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

static inline int32_t _foo (int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    // Do foo stuff here. This works when called directly.
}

// But calling via this alias crashes...
int32_t _bar (int32_t x, int32_t y) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("_foo")));

#endif
```

Have I done something wrong? Has anyone else seen this cause a program to crash?

Comment: Try to remove the `static inline` qualifiers from `_foo()`.

Comment: Removed `inline` to no effect, cannot remove the `static` without resulting in multiple definition errors (foo.h is included in more than one file).

Comment: Then put `_foo()` in a C file, and make it a regular symbol. Aliasing is a linker feature, thus aliasing an inlined function makes little sense.